# How to automatically connect to a Windows network folder?

Tags: lan, shared-folders

Through the normal processes I enter my shared music folder on my Windows computer, i.e.: Places > Network > Windows pc > Music. After rebooting my Ubuntu laptop, however, this connection isn't automatically set again.

My question: How do I get Ubuntu to automatically connect to that shared folder after login (while first checking whether the Windows computer is 'online')?

This because I added the folder to the Banshee Library, and I currently first have to go to the shared folder manually before Banshee can play the files.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking to auto mount the Windows share... I'm pretty sure this will help you https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: OK, I followed the guide on the wiki page you linked to, but I now get this error:
`mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`
Isn't there a way to do this via a GUI?
At least I no know that I'll have to get Ubuntu automatically mount the folder, thanks!